# Can't make push notification Work with Sinch

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, sinch

I'm trying to receive voip(and regular) push notification work on my app for sinch calls.

The code its already receiving calls when the app is in foreground. 
And background with local nofitications

And the certificate for push is working sending pushes with pusher app in mac, i follow the tutorials and dont know what i'm missing

My code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, SINCallClientDelegate, SINCallDelegate, SINMessageClientDelegate, SINClientDelegate, SINManagedPushDelegate {

var msgClient:SINMessageClient!
var window: UIWindow?
var applicationKey:String!
var applicationSecret:String!
var environmentHost:String!

var voipClient:SINClient!
var push:SINManagedPush!

func requestUserNotificationPermission() {
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    self.push.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo)
}


func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    self.handleLocalNotification(notification)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    self.push.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
}

func startSinch() {
    if self.voipClient == nil {
        self.push.registerUserNotificationSettings()
        let userID = "partner-4" //fixed for tests
        self.voipClient = Sinch.clientWithApplicationKey(applicationKey, applicationSecret:applicationSecret,environmentHost:environmentHost,userId: userID)

        self.voipClient.delegate = self;
        //commented to test push but is working
        //self.voipClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true)
        self.voipClient.enableManagedPushNotifications()
        self.voipClient.setSupportCalling(true)
        self.voipClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
        self.voipClient.start()
        self.voipClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection()

        self.msgClient = self.voipClient.messageClient()
        self.msgClient.delegate = self

    }

}

func managedPush(managedPush: SINManagedPush!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, forType pushType: String!) {
    self.handleRemoteNotification(payload)
}


func handleRemoteNotification(userInfo: NSDictionary){
    if (self.voipClient == nil) {
        self.startSinch()
    }
    self.voipClient.relayRemotePushNotification(userInfo as [NSObject : AnyObject])
}

func client(client: SINCallClient!, localNotificationForIncomingCall call: SINCall!) -> SINLocalNotification! {
    let notification = SINLocalNotification()
    notification.alertAction = "test"
    notification.alertBody = "test"
    notification.soundName = "notification-sound.caf"
    return notification
}

func relayLocalNotification(notification: UILocalNotification) -> SINNotificationResult{
    return self.voipClient.relayLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Comment: I cant set the complete implementation, but if you use managed push have you checked out our sample apps for push?

Comment: yeah, but all the sample apps are in obj-c, and my project swift, i just get the code from the sample and translated to swift.

All functions worked except the push

Comment: Hey I am having the same issue when working with local notifications. Did you get it to work?